# How do I prove Poisson appraches Normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, probability-distributions

I want to prove why the mean and variance of a $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, is different when the time index approaches infinite (it's approximated by the mean and variance of a Normal).

For example: 
$$
N_k = N_1 + (N_2 - N_1) + (N_3 - N_2) + ... + (N_k - N_{k-1})
$$

Using CLT:
$\frac{N_k - k\lambda}{\sqrt{k\lambda}}$ is normally distributed (in the limit).

I want to answer why is that a Poisson R.V. characterized by $\mathbb{E}[X] = \lambda$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X] = \lambda$.
Because when it approaches a normal distribution, $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}[Z] = \sigma^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Poisson distribution does not approach the normal distribution, the *centered* Poisson distribution does. More precisely, if $X_\lambda$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, then $Y_\lambda$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable $Z$, where $Y_\lambda=(X_\lambda-\lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$. In particular, for every $\lambda$, $E[Y_\lambda]=E[Z]=0$ and $\mathrm{var}(Y_\lambda)=\mathrm{var}(Z)=1$ (in your language, $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=1$).

Comment: Note that the title of the question does not match its content.

Comment: But, isn't that case with any random variable? The CLT says (X - mean)/standard_dev is normally distributed? Am I confused with my concetps?

Comment: The CLT certainly does not say that Y = (X - mean)/standard_dev is normally distributed. Note that Y is normally distributed only when X itself is normally distributed.

Comment: So the difference between a centered Poisson and CLT is that CLT says that a sample mean is normally distributed over infinite trials and centered Poisson is over once instance.

Comment: Ok, so I just worked through an example with moment generating function and was able to prove mathematically why a centered poisson is normally distributed, but how can I explain this in plain English?

Comment: Once again, *a centered (P)oisson is* NOT *normally distributed*.

Comment: The normal distribution is a family of distributions with two parameters: its mean and its variance. N(0,1) is only a particular case. Then we can say that the Poisson distribution approaches the normal distribution. Right?

Comment: @Josh Are you able to add the details of your proof to your post (Question)? I realize this is an old question.